# Service is not working android marshmallow devices when app is kill start at android?

Tags: android, service

Here I attached my code,I created a service which runs both cases while my app is in background and killed state. It is not running on android marshmallow devices, but it works on other devices. When I check other devices, Log will be executed when the app is kill state, only version 6 , not executed.

```
public class SensorService extends Service {
        public int counter=0;
        public SensorService(Context applicationContext) {
            super();
            Log.e("HERE", "here I am!");
        }

        public SensorService() {
        }

        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
            startTimer();
            return START_STICKY;
        }
```

When comes to destroy again I will call the service, It will go to broadcast receive, and then start service function will call.

```
        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            Log.e("EXIT", "ondestroy!");
            Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent("sales.com.ActivityRecognition.RestartSensor");
            sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
            stoptimertask();
        }

        private Timer timer;
        private TimerTask timerTask;
        long oldTime=0;
        public void startTimer() {
            timer = new Timer();
            initializeTimerTask();
            timer.schedule(timerTask, 1000, 1000); //
        }
        public void initializeTimerTask() {
            timerTask = new TimerTask() {
                public void run() {
                    Log.e("in timer", "in timer ++++  "+ (counter++));
                }
            };
        }

        public void stoptimertask() {
            //stop the timer, if it's not already null
            if (timer != null) {
                timer.cancel();
                timer = null;
            }
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return null;

    }
```

Below code for Broadcast Receiver code : app works, when i click back button, if the app was killed state, it is not working, other devices services running.

```
    public class SensorRestarterBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.e(SensorRestarterBroadcastReceiver.class.getSimpleName(), "Service Stops! Oooooooooooooppppssssss!!!!");

         //   context.startService(new Intent(context, SensorService.class));

            Intent i = new Intent(context, SensorService.class);
            context.startService(i);

        }

    }
```

Comment: SensorRestarterBroadcastReceiver where are are you registering your service?

Comment: tested without registering service that case also not working